# Should I use Python native multithread or Multiple Tasks in Airflow?

Tags: python, mongodb, airflow

I'm refactoring a .NET application to airflow. This .NET application uses multiple threads to extract and process data from a mongoDB (Without multiple threads the process takes ~ 10hrs, with multi threads i can reduce this) .

In each documment on mongoDB I have a key value named`process`. This value is used to control which thread process the documment. I'm going to develop an Airflow DAG to optimize this process. My doubt is about performance and the best way to do this.

My application should have multiple tasks (I will control the `process` variable in the input of the python method). Or should I use only 1 task and use Python MultiThreading inside this task? The image below illustrates my doubt.

[Multi Task X Single Task (Multi Threading)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CpQ6.jpg)

I know that using MultiTask I'm going to do more DB Reads (1 per task). Although, using Python Multi Threading I know I'll have to do a lot of control processing inside de task method. What is the best, fastest and optimized way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the nature of your processing.

Multi-threading in Python can be limiting because of GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) - there are some operations that require exclusive lock, and this limit the parallelism it can achieve. Especially if you mix CPU and I/O operations the effects might be that a lot of time is spent by threads waiting for the lock. But it really depends on what you do - you need to experiment to see if GIL affects your multithreading.

Multiprocessing (which is used by Airflow for Local Executor) is better because each process runs effectively a separate Python interpreter. So each process has it's own GIL - at the expense of resources used (each process uses it's own memory, sockets and so on). Each task in Airlfow will run in a separate process.

However Airflow offers a bit more - it also offers multi-machine. You can run  separate workers With X processes on Y machines, effectively running up to X*Y processes at a time.

Unfortunately, Airflow is (currently) not well suited to run dynamic number of parallel tasks of the same type. Specifically if you would like to split load to process to N pieces and run each piece in a separate task - this would only really work if N is constant and does not change over time for the same DAG (like if you know you have 10 machines, with 4 CPUs, you's typically want to run 10*4 = 40 tasks at a time, so you'd have to split your job into 40 tasks. And it cannot change dynamically between runs really - you'd have to write your DAG to run 40 parallel tasks every time it runs.

Not sure if I helped, but there is no single "best optimised" answer - you need to experiment and check what works best for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it certainly helped me better understand how I'm going to solve my problem.

Comment: Hey Jarek! Nice to see you here on Overflow as well! Question - how do dynamic task mapping fit into this concurrent task execution? As far as I know dynamic task mapping allows you to create tasks dynamically (i.e. at run-time) but these do not necessarily execute concurrently, right?

Comment: They actually do - this is all but given because each Dynamic task is - by definition - separate Airflow task and it is run not only in separate interpreter but (depending on your setup) might even run on a different machine.

Comment: @JarekPotiuk can you explain: "Airflow is (currently) not well suited to run dynamic number of parallel tasks of the same type" ? can't I just connect a task for the input of the dynamic task - which will affectively make the dynamic task mapping to execute on a non-constant task number? as the [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#task-generated-mapping](official doc suggest)

Comment: Sure "currently" (2 years ago) is the key. It's not valid any more. Airflow can do it now.

Comment: For a large number of tasks, dynamic-tasks would also have its caveats. If your tasks take long to complete, the compute resources occupied by the tasks would be quite large and require you to scale up your Airflow cluster. This would be true even if the tasks are IO bound. A way around this would be to use the "deferrable" tasks approach. It would require you to set up the "Triggerer" service as well.